# Visual Studio - Exclude moles files from search

Tags: visual-studio-2010, moles, pex-and-moles

I know Visual Studio allows you to specify what kinds of files you *want* to search in the find and replace dialog, which works well in general.  Generated moles files, however, have a path ending in "m.g.cs".  When searching for .cs files, these are also searched, which produces a ton of noise in the find results.  Is there a way to specify that files matching "*m.g.cs" should be ignored in the find and replace?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a new item (folder set) to the **Look in** drop-down list?

Here's how it's done:
[image: adding a folder set]